# Azure website is slow if it has'nt been used for a while

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Got some azure websites.

When I visit it sometimes can be very slow to load (3-4s). If I refresh, it's fast (cache disabled). If I wait a few hours, it's slow again.

It's like Azure is shutting the site down if has not been visited for some time. I'm running it on windows, cost free version.

Is there any setting in Azure where I can disable this?

Comment: CSharpRocks's Answer doesn't help you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move to a paid pricing tier (Basic and +) and turn **Always On** on.